# Is the Monero genesis block reward spendable?

Tags: cryptocurrency-comparison, available-outputs, block-reward, genesisblock

Is the Monero genesis block reward spendable?

The 50 BTC in the [Bitcoin genesis block](https://www.blocktrail.com/BTC/block/0) can [never be spent](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/10009/why-can-t-the-genesis-block-coinbase-be-spent). Are the 17.592186 XMR from the [Monero genesis block](https://explorer.xmr.my/block/0) capable of being spent?

If they cannot be spent, would transactions from that block (assuming someone had the private key to authorize them) be rejected for the [same reason](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/10019/35696) as Bitcoin?

> Satoshi decided not to add the coinbase transaction from the genesis block to the global transaction database. Thus all the nodes in the network would reject the block.

Can the address (if we knew what it was) associated with this [tx hash](https://explorer.xmr.my/tx/c88ce9783b4f11190d7b9c17a69c1c52200f9faaee8e98dd07e6811175177139) that received coins from the first Monero block receive XMR transactions the same way that the [Bitcoin address](https://www.blocktrail.com/BTC/address/1A1zP1eP5QGefi2DMPTfTL5SLmv7DivfNa) associated with the genenis block [has](https://www.blocktrail.com/BTC/address/1A1zP1eP5QGefi2DMPTfTL5SLmv7DivfNa/transactions)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is spendable. There are a lot of clones which use the genesis block reward as premined coins

Comment: Did they try to spend those yet ? :)

Comment: I helped a couple of networks doing that and it requires just a small edit in the code to spend. Is it unsafe?

Comment: I have no reason to think it would be. I just pointed out that your answer did not quite imply they could be spent yet :)

Comment: Can you reference the source code or in some way prove that they are spendable?

Comment: Here are the changes for Bytecoin (it should be easily portable to Monero):
https://github.com/forknote/cryptonote-generator/blob/master/extensions/genesis-block-reward.json