# How to mine monero genesis block reward (monero fork)

Tags: monerod, genesisblock

When i start mining it start from height 1 not height 0. [image]

Answer (score 1):

The genesis block is not mined, it is just made.

See some details:
[How can I create a new Monero genesis block?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2886/how-can-i-create-a-new-monero-genesis-block)

Comment: Sorry, i mean genesis block reward. Already created genesis block but stuck at mining genesis block reward

Comment: @Samjoe This reward can't be spent. https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2642/is-the-monero-genesis-block-reward-spendable